# show wfs attributes as label on selection

Tags: styles, label, openlayers-3, geoserver

I am trying to show attribute of wfs gml layer from geoserver as label in my openlayer3 application. I am successful to get label as text but unable to access the particular attribute 'name'. Given is the code I am working with.

```js
var sourceWFS = new ol.source.Vector({
    loader: function (extent) {
        $.ajax('..../geoserver/harry/ows?', {
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                service: 'WFS',
                version: '1.1.0',
                request: 'GetFeature',
                typename: 'ABC',
                srsname: 'EPSG:3857',
                geometryField:'geometry',
                bbox: extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:3857'
            }

        }).done(function (response) {
            sourceWFS.addFeatures(formatWFS.readFeatures(response));
        });
    },
    strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.tile(ol.tilegrid.createXYZ()),
    strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox,
    projection: 'EPSG:3857',

});
var layerWFS = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: sourceWFS
});

var interaction;

var interactionSelectPointerMove = new ol.interaction.Select({
    condition: ol.events.condition.pointerMove
});

var interactionSelect = new ol.interaction.Select({


    style: new ol.style.Style({ 

            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: 'rgba(255,0,0,1.0)',
                width: 1
            }),
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.5)'
            }),
            text: new ol.style.Text({
                text:("abcd")
            })


        })
});

var interactionSnap = new ol.interaction.Snap({
    source: layerWFS.getSource()
});
```

I am getting `abcd` as label on selection

Answer (score 1):

You will need a style function to set the text in the style from whichever feature property you wish to display

```
var selectStyle = new ol.style.Style({ 

            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: 'rgba(255,0,0,1.0)',
                width: 1
            }),
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.5)'
            }),
            text: new ol.style.Text({
                text:("abcd")
            })

        });



var interactionSelect = new ol.interaction.Select({

    style: function(feature) {

            selectStyle.getText().setText(feature.get('name'));
            return selectStyle;

        }

});
```

Comment: i tried the same but unable to access the attributes i am not getting any errors yet labels are not displayed.Is   selectStyle.getText().setText(feature.get('name'));
correct syntax to get labels from  geoserver layer

Comment: My answer was missing the `return` line

Comment: If you are unsure which property to use you could use `console.log(feature.getProperties());` to check what is available.

Answer (score 1):

You will not get any attribute that is "hidden" by a GML attribute by default. The most common "missing" attributes are `name` and `id`. You can turn off this (standard complying) behaviour by checking the `Override GML Attributes` in the WFS services page for the version of GML your client is requesting.

[image: relevant part of WFS service settings page]

Answer (score 0):

What you are actually displaying is the "abcd" string itself and not the value of "abcd" property.
To access some feature property value in an `ol.Style` you must use a `StyleFunction` as follows :

```
    style: function(feature, resolution){
             return new ol.style.Style({ 
                    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                        color: 'rgba(255,0,0,1.0)',
                        width: 1
                    }),
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                       color: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.5)'
                    }),
                    text: new ol.style.Text({
                       text: feature.get("abcd");
                    })
              })
           }
```